# controlling R output

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
print(x)
```

is returning as output:

```
[1] -0.67604293 -0.49002147  1.50190943  0.48438935 -0.17091949  0.39868189
[7] -0.57922386 -0.08172699 -0.82327067  0.07005629
```

I suppose that R is having a limit of characters per line or something and that is why is splitting the result in 2 lines. I am building a service based on the output of R.

What should I do in order to get it in one line?

Comment: I don't know about the specifics of what you're trying to do, but does options("width") help?

Comment: I think you may be correct. Why not put it into an answer so I can vote you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Than it is better to tell R to output things in a way that will be convenient to your wrapper; check out string functions like `paste()`, `sprintf()` and push the result into output with `cat()`; for instance putting numbers in a column could look like:

```
x<-rnorm(10)
cat(paste(x,collapse="\n"),"\n")
```

what outputs just:

```
0.889105851072202
0.86920550247321
0.817785758768382
-0.0194490361401052
1.13386492568134
0.0786139738004322
0.7431631392675
0.93881227070957
0.534225167458455
1.08265812080696
```

Comment: But not really an answer to the Q posed. Roman's answer does that. The only reason the printed output spans more than one line is the value of `options("width")` **or** the console width if it sets `options("width")` in whatever interface to R Elzo is using.

Comment: @Gavin I am aware, yet the OP stated that he want it to simplify the transfer to the other program... deprettifying prettified output is always a bad idea in this case, especially when one can easily bypass prettifier.

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust the printing width in R by adjusting the [options("width")](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_man-2.9.0/library/base/html/options.html) option. If you give us more details about your project, maybe we could be of better use.

Comment: You set it this way: options(width= 150)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everybody for their responses. I want to publish a new way of doing it that for me was the best and maybe someone else will need this reference. As I am building a webservice I will be using [phpSerialize](http://cran.uib.no/web/packages/phpSerialize/index.html) to control the output so I can [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it in PHP.

```
library(phpSerialize)
x<-rnorm(10)
x = phpSerialize(x)
cat(x)
```